# Context-aware web services

Tags: android, semantics

I am starting an MSc thesis and I investigating in the field of context-aware mashups.  Do you guys know if there are any standard which have already been set on the way the context or point of interests are sent to the server?  Like location, social information, language and other information about the mobile being sent in a particular format like a DOM or tree like structure or maybe xml.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to now there is no all around approach used for all service descriptions so usually there are no formal specifications for web services. But there are some general academic approaches to specify web services in web service repositories with the help of service specifications by using predicates and pre- post- conditions.

An good, but too complicated and failed approach: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Description_Discovery_and_Integration

More up to date research:
http://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=a.fiech+web+service+repository&btnG=&hl=de&as_sdt=0%2C
and
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2252122/DesignAndImplementationOfAWebServiceRepositoy.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this is an answer to what your looking for but may help:

[Geolocation API Specification W3C](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html)

Comment: I was thinking in more general terms not necessarily location.  I am trying to search for current standards, such that I do not research in something that already exists or something that nobody have started working on.  Did some searches, but nothing that can be used as a base.